# Is there a way to force an automatic unmount of a volume under some conditions?

Tags: linux, security, ssh, backup

Where I work, we have very light security policy which allows users to connect to their personal mail accounts and so on.

Every user is root on his own computer and there is no centralized account management. It's pretty much like all computers where standalone/personal computers on the same local area network.

The only exception is that the sys-admins demand that we put a key in our `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` so they can backup our files. Fair enough, except that I'm a bit paranoid.

I have nothing against having mandatory backups (I even agree it is a good thing) but on some occasion, I plug my personal ciphered usb key that contains my personal password database (keepass) and I'd like to avoid that its content gets backuped.

So here is my question:

Is there a way for me to automatically unmount the USB key volume or even better: to delay the root login from an external host until my usb key is unmounted/plugged ?

What would be the easiest/safest way to do that ?

Note: My employer actually agrees with this setup.

---

Note #2: Reading the comments, I would say I now understand what is wrong in asking that, and how it could seem I'm trying to piss my sysadmin. I can't blame anyone for not trusting me of course, and I sincerely want to apologize if at any point I made it sound like I was "smarter than the sysadmin" or anything. This question expected a purely technical answer but a purely technical answer would not have been a good answer. As they say: *"Science without conscience is but the ruin of the soul..."* Thanks to you all for your feedback.

Comment: The core question is who owns the computer?  If the computer is owned by your employer you may not be standing on very firm ground to limit IT's access.  Also consider this, backups are for your protection, if you put something in place to prevent centralized backups and something goes wrong, oh well right?  Not quote so if you also lost many hours of deliverables (work).

Comment: Ok, ignoring the fact that this type of setup is absolutely insane, this question is off-topic and doesn't exactly fit within the scope of this site as outlined in our [faq].

Comment: @MDMarra: I read the FAQ but I admit I fail to see where I violate the conditions of acceptance. Does my question really fall to the "system misuse case" when my employer explicitely gives his permission for this setup ?

Comment: The faq says that inappropriate questions include :"circumvention of security or policy". Until you explained it, that's what this sounded like.

Comment: This site is also not for end user questions, so regardless of the whys and wherefores the question remains off topic.

Comment: @ereOn You're not a systems admin, you're a user. The first line says `Server Fault is for Information Technology Professionals needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a professional capacity.`

Comment: @MDMarra: I'm not a sysadmin, sure. But what makes you think I'm not an "Information Technology Professional" ? Put otherwise, this question would probably have gotten technical answers. I chose to tell the truth and I don't really understand the rationale into only answering to sysadmins here. If a non-sysadmin asks something that a real sysadmin could ask, why does it matter what his real job is as long as it might help other people ? (I'm not talking about my own question (which was bad), but about an hypothetical acceptable/good question.)

Comment: The answer to your question is simple: *Contact your system administrator, and request that USB media be exempted from the backup of your workstation.*  If your company is truly OK with you having personal devices connected to your workstation they should not mind ignoring them during backups (in fact for space and liability reasons they probably *don't want* to back up your data...)

Comment: @voretaq7: My sysadmin already agreed not to backup this key (he is the one that told me having an ciphered usb key for that was a good idea). I was just wanting to make sure it couldn't happen by mistake. Not that I don't trust him, but if any mistake happens ever, then my password database will be writen in stone somewhere I have no control over. I guess the accepted answer is the only real one: "just don't connect that usb key to the computer".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to keep your employer from your "personal" data is to keep your personal data off your employer's computer.  Period.

Comment: +1 Works perfectly every time!

Comment: That sure is the best way. My employer allows me to connect to my personal accounts using a company computer and even agrees not to backup my password database. I'm actually asking how to do it, not if I'm allowed to. I can understand how this can seem insane to sysadmins. Fair enough. But can't I take advantage of the extra permissions I was given by my employer ?

Comment: @ereOn - walk into a police station and ask them for safe-cracking tips - see how you get on ;)

Comment: If your employer has given you permission to do this, then ask your company's sysadmins to help you. If they have trouble, send them here :-)

Comment: @Chopper3: The sad thing is I'm pretty sure I would have get an answer if I hadn't stated the the key in question contained personal data but some company specific secret instead. I guess honesty isn't always well rewarded. Lesson learnt.

Comment: @mfinni: The sysadmin actually sent me here. To quote him: "I won't reject this setup but I won't spend any of my time to help you set it up." And I can't actually blame him.

Comment: Aha - makes sense.

Comment: ereOn - it's not a matter of honesty. Think of it this way - your sysadmin, the one who is paid to fix your problems, doesn't want to spend any time on this issue because it's not work-related. We do the same job as that guy, and we're not paid for the answers we give on this site. Until you explained that this was cool with your employer, this sounded like an attempted subversion of policy. Thus, no good answers from us for that.

Comment: @ereOn - I think people here are just appalled by the setup of those systems, I can understand, there WILL be a day when it all stops working and that would worry me as an employee. It's quite odd in a way that effectively zero time has been put into setting this up, it makes me wonder what other significant corners have been cut too?

Comment: @mfinni: Well, I guess I get that now. I honestly thought it wasn't like I was asking "How to decipher my coworker's encrypted disk" but it seems rather important to you guys. I guess I would act the same were it about a question of software programming. Thank for taking the time for explaining your point of view. Not the answer I expected but a good answer anyway.

Comment: @ereOn  My answer has nothing to do with feeling that this is a circumvention of policy by you.  (I disagree with the question closure and downvoting.)  This what I find is the best for keeping your employer from getting/snooping your personal stuff, and is gleaned from a lot of time on both sides of this issue. I advocate the same perspective when the business asks me about putting company information on user's personal property (like with BYOD).  I say the converse of what I said to you - keep business materials off employees personal property. Buy them a company smartphone or laptop to use.

Comment: @ereOn And, just so you don't think I'm blowing you off... there's really no good "technical" way to do what you want to do.  If the data's unencrypted (as it needs to be to be used), it can be accessed, copied, altered, etc., no way around it.  If they have root access, which they do, there's no way to stop them from (in theory) doing any damn thing they want on the system you use for work, no way around that either.  So really, the answer is - you can't prevent `root` from getting this data (if someone using that account wants it), unless you keep it off the computer in question.

Comment: @HopelessN00b: No offense taken. I guess I was just a bit surprised by all the harsh comments that arised from this question. Re-reading my question, I understand how it could seem like I would want to piss my sysadmin and I can't blame people to think that was my intent. Thank you again for your explanations. Out of curiosity, how do you guys cope with the time you need to login on personnal accounts but only have a work computer at your disposal ?

Comment: @ereOn Actually, that is forbidden.  Literally no one in the organization has the ability to do so from a work computer.  (Though if anyone high enough asked, they'd get it on account of `executive privilege` and all.)  I bring in my 4G USB card, and a small personal tablet/laptop, as well as my smartphone.  I presume other people do the same, though, straight up, I see people with nothing to do reading books (because they're not allowed to browse the web) or even napping, so it's not like this makes anyone more productive, but... the rules is the rules, and they pay me too much to argue. :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to mount the key in a place in the filesystem that isn't already backed up. I assume they're not backing up /, /tmp, etc. Find out what they are backing up, and then mount the drive elsewhere.

Comment: Mounting it in /tmp is a very good idea. Thanks.

I accepted the first answer for ethical reasons which I explained in the question, but upvoted this one for fairness.